# How to find out changes done by a fork (not coming from upstream repo)

Tags: git, github

Lets say there is project on github and a fork of it which has lagged behind for 3 years.

The commits shown on the fork page include commits from upstream and comparing the changes does not help as it shows also commits merged from upstream.

Is there a way from github interface or using git commands to inspect only the changes commited by the fork (not coming from upstream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using git log by range `git log master..feature`

for example `git log origin/master..[forked branch goes here]`